# Subset data and calculate time difference

Tags: r

I have the following data frame and I want to calculate time difference between oldest and newest dates for each user.

```
> data1
      date    user  PC
1 1/4/2010 BAC0081 PC1
2 1/5/2010 BAC0081 PC2
3 1/6/2010 BAC0081 PC3
4 1/7/2010 BAC0081 PC4
5 1/4/2010 BAC0082 PC5
6 1/5/2010 BAC0082 PC6
7 1/6/2010 BAC0082 PC7
>
```

Results I would expect is;

**BAC0081 3 days**

**BAC0082 2 days**

I couldn't find an efficient way to perform this function. Can anyone suggests me a proper way of doing this pls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your date column formatted correctly:

```
lapply(split(data1[, 1], data1[, 2]), function(x) range(x)[2] - range(x)[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That works fine for me.